# Bottom of one layout in the middle of another layout vertically in android xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to create the below layout, but not sure how to do it.

[image]

height of both blue layout and white layout is set to "wrap_content" and therefor they don't have a constant height.

The point is, I want the bottom of blue layout to always be in the middle of white layout(vertically). I have no idea how to do it using constraint or relative layout.

I searched but couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: if you are using relative layout than just do below and than top margin into -20dp like

Comment: In that case there will be a 20dp space, it will not always be in the middle. if the white layout gets bigger, it won't be in the middle anymore

Comment: use contrain layout than and gudie line

Comment: @Keivan.k you can add a negative margin programmatically. The margin can be calculated as the (getMeasuredHeight()/2) of the white layout.

Comment: @Amitpandey could you explain more?

Comment: @Ranzz Thanks, yes that is also doable. However, I would rather to have it done in the xml rather than in the java side

Comment: i give the ans please check i use guide line with constraint layout in this case if you use any device its adjust its self according to device screen

Comment: @Amitpandey seems very interesting, never knew about that. I will check that in a few hours and let you know. Many thanks

Comment: thats the reason we alll use contrant layout its orovide you lots of opation like barrier group guide line screen percentange etc

Answer (score 1):

modify this accordingly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/credentials_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_logo">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_light"
                    android:text="L O G I N"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MOBILE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/mobileNumberET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="PASSWORD"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round"
        android:text="L O G I N"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_light"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/credentials_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I don't include border radius so take care of it..)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="#8F2A2A"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="#B8C159"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Here My Ans check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_16"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_16"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_5"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/card_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp_10"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_5"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/card_container"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/card_container"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline">


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constraint layout as parent and then constraint the topOfSmallComponent to the bottomOfBigComponent. Then again constraint the bottomOfSmallComponent to the bottomOf BigComponent.

Example code below:

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="your_blue_items_id"
   
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="your_blue_items_id"
```